# Организация ACL для пользователей без администрирования СУБД

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, архитектура

Коллеги, добрый день.

Подскажите, как организовать группы пользователей с разными привилегиями НЕ используя логику административной части сервера postgre. Поясню: если решать задачу через админку, то придется под каждого пользователя заводить учётку - что очень не хотелось бы, ибо пользователей > 1000 и хотелось бы ограничиться одной учёткой под взаимодействующих пользователей. А так в моей базе есть таблица "Пользователи" к которой нужно привязать права.

Comment: И в чем вопрос?

Comment: Сейчас у меня функции разграничения доступа и авторизации возложены на клиентское ПО (вся логика рулится в запросах). Может быть есть какие-то методики или решения, когда мы храним пользователей и данные вместе, но проверку привелегий как-то автоматизируем?

Comment: @0xd9 Вы даете доступ к чему? К объектам БД (таблицы, вью, и т. д.)? К записям в таблицах? Кто такие "взаимодействующие пользователи"? "под каждого пользователя заводить учётку" - вы имеете в виду для каждого пользователя заводить логин в БД через учетку БД? Или у вас есть отдельное приложение со своими пользователями?

Comment: @Dmitry, даю доступ к записям в таблицах.
"взаимодействующие пользователи" — пользователи сервиса, объединенные в группы (администраторы, менеджеры, клиенты) и работающие с ресурсами (документы, события), к которым у них есть доступ (доступ разграничивается на базе групп). "Заводить учетку" - заводить логин в БД через учетку СУБД, да, верно.

Comment: "Или у вас есть отдельное приложение со своими пользователями?" Сейчас данные о пользователях хранятся в общей базе с бизнес-данными.